# How do I make a word list into an order by most used to least?

Tags: javascript, python

So I have a file of 100000 words. I'm wondering how I can make it so it creates a file saying "the: 10282 times" "and: 322 times" "sadfas222: 1 times"

This is what the text file look likes:

```
asdf
jkasdf
the
sadf
asdn
23kl
asdf
qer
f
asdf
r
2
r
fsd
fa
sdf
asd
far2
sdv
as
df
asdf
asdf
```

Comment: Javascript, or Python? Why the "database" tag? Please [edit] your question to provide an example of the input file format - not all 100000 words, obviously, but to show if the words separated by commas, spaces, newlines, or...?

Comment: Where are your words stored. I mean javascript object, database, json or something else?

Comment: It's in a text file. txt

Comment: Javascript or Python? Please show what you have tried. No spoonfeeding here.

Comment: @asdfasdasdf22222 reading text file from javascript? are you using node?

Comment: Javascript, or Python, or either?

Answer (score 5):

In Node.js and after doing `npm i split2 through2 -S`

```
const fs = require('fs')
const split = require('split2')
const through = require('through2')

const words = {}

fs.createReadStream('words.txt')
  .pipe(split())
  .pipe(through(write, end))


function write (buf, enc, next) {
  const word = buf.toString()
  words[word] = ++words[word] || 1

  next()
}

function end () {
  Object.keys(words)
    .sort((a, b) => words[b] - words[a])
    .forEach(word => {
      console.log(`${word}: ${words[word]} times`)
    })
}
```

Comment: +1 I was writing a very similar answer until I saw this one get added, and it sums up what I was doing (I was using native streams though). The main thing that I would like to point out is that while this does allocate memory for the object of words, the file itself is never read into memory, at least not all at once.

This means that your computer won't choke if you hand it a file that's larger than it's memory resources.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify this a bit for accepting input from a text file

```
var letterArray = "asdf\njkasdf\nthe\nsadf".split('\n');

function count(letterArray) {

    let mapping = {};

    for (let i=0; i < letterArray.length; i++){
        if (mapping[letterArray[i]] !== undefined){ // if the letter already exists in the mapping increment it
            mapping[letterArray[i]] += 1;
        }else { //if the letter does not exist add it and initialize it
            mapping[letterArray[i]] = 1;
        }
    }

    return mapping;
}

console.log("count: ", count(letterArray));
```

Comment: What is your `else if` condition supposed to do? The `if` before that has already handled the case where the word is in `mapping`, so just a simple `else` with no condition is all you need at that point.

Comment: just copy pasted from an old code I had, and there were other else ifs after that else if, but forgot to modify it

Answer (score 0):

I used python approach to get what you expected

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

def wordcount(data):
    cv = CountVectorizer(min_df=0, strip_accents="ascii", decode_error ="ignore")

    counts = cv.fit_transform([data]).toarray().ravel()
    words = np.array(cv.get_feature_names())

    counts = map(int, counts)

    words = [i.tolist() for i in words]
    words = [x.encode('UTF8') for x in words]

    unsorted_result = zip(words, counts)
    print sorted(unsorted_result,key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Send you data as a string to this function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` from `collections` module for that:

```
content = open("textfile.txt").read()
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(content.splitlines())
for x in c.most_common():
    print("{}: {} times".format(x[0], x[1]))
```

Usage:

```
In [7]: contet = """asdf
   ...: jkasdf
   ...: the
   ...: sadf
   ...: asdn
   ...: 23kl
   ...: asdf
   ...: qer
   ...: f
   ...: asdf
   ...: r
   ...: 2
   ...: r
   ...: fsd
   ...: fa
   ...: sdf
   ...: asd
   ...: far2
   ...: sdv
   ...: as
   ...: df
   ...: asdf
   ...: asdf"""

In [8]: from collections import Counter

In [9]: c = Counter(content.splitlines())

In [10]: c.most_common()
Out[10]:
[('asdf', 5),
 ('r', 2),
 ('f', 1),
 ('23kl', 1),
 ('as', 1),
 ('df', 1),
 ('sadf', 1),
 ('qer', 1),
 ('sdf', 1),
 ('jkasdf', 1),
 ('sdv', 1),
 ('the', 1),
 ('2', 1),
 ('fsd', 1),
 ('asdn', 1),
 ('fa', 1),
 ('asd', 1),
 ('far2', 1)]
```

And loop over the results in c:

```
In [11]: for x in c.most_common():
   ....:     print("{}: {} times".format(x[0], x[1]))
   ....:
asdf: 5 times
r: 2 times
f: 1 times
23kl: 1 times
as: 1 times
df: 1 times
sadf: 1 times
qer: 1 times
sdf: 1 times
jkasdf: 1 times
sdv: 1 times
the: 1 times
2: 1 times
fsd: 1 times
asdn: 1 times
fa: 1 times
asd: 1 times
far2: 1 times
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd recommend doing this is java.  It has better tools than javascript, but this can also be done in javascript.  Load the whole list into an array.  Then use a sort method to sort the entire list.  In js its just .sort().  This will put words that are the same next to each other in the list.  Then use a loop to walk this list from top to bottom.  You will need two variables, lastWord and currentWord.  Everytime the word changes put the last word into an new array along with how many times you saw it.  You'll obviously also need a counter variable.  So you'll be walking your sorted array and dumping results into another one.  You'll also need logic that detects when you hit the end of the list so you can write the last world.  This is the kind of problem that you'll often see in programming classes in school.  Have fun.